# Analytic solution to differential equations with reflected arguments

Tags: integration, derivatives, reflection

I am curious about whether or not there are any techniques to find solutions to functional differential equations where the arguments of $y,y',...$ are only either of  $\pm x$ (which could be considered a special case of $kx$). For instance, consider the (linear) differential equation:

$$y(x)+y'(-x)= f(x)$$

I was able to find, essentially by guessing, that the homogeneous solution is:

$$y=A(\sin(x)-\cos(x))$$

and we have some particular integrals such as:

$$f(x)=c \implies y(x) = c$$
$$f(x) = x \implies y(x) = x-1$$
$$f(x)=e^{\pm x} \implies y(x) = \frac{e^x \mp e^{-x}}{2}$$
$$f(x)=\frac{e^{-x} \pm e^{x}}{2} \implies y(x) = \frac{e^{\pm x}}{2}$$

If we let $y(x) = \sin(ax+b)$, varying $a,b$ affects the amplitude of the output, but, curiously, not the phase. Thus, I couldn't figure out $f(x) = \sin(x)$.

Other than computing power series solutions, are there any ways that this problem could be approached, especially for higher-order analogues?

Comment: You can try assuming that $y(x)$ is odd or even and then $y(-x)=-y(x)\text{ or } y(x)$

Comment: @TymaGaidash Good suggestion. Especially since if $y$ is odd/even, it follows that $y'$ is even/odd.

Comment: Let $u(x) = y(-x)$.  Then $u'(x) = -y'(-x)$.  This gives the system of equations $y(x) - u'(x) = f(x)$ and $u(x) + y'(x) = f(-x)$.  (This latter comes from $x \mapsto -x$ in the original equation.  It has the advantage that the inhomogeneous term, which is usually explicitly given, is the only one with an argument different from "$x$".)  Now solve this system like any other first order linear system of ODEs.

Comment: @EricTowers Good idea. Seems like that pretty much solves it. Thanks!

Comment: Ah...  Left out:  Then, at the end, set $u(x) = y(-x)$ to solve for constraints on the constants of integration.

Comment: For instance, with $f(x) = c$, the system solves to $u(x) = c + C_1 \cos x + C_2 \sin x$, $y(x) = c - C_1 \sin x + C_2 \cos x$.  Then, setting $u(x) = y(-x)$, we get the constraint $C_2 = C_1$.  So the original equation's solution is $y(x) = c + C_1(-\sin x + \cos x)$.

Comment: @EricTowers By the way, my motivation for this was considering the reflection property of the gamma function. I was wondering if it was possible to show that $y = \frac{1}{\Gamma(z) \Gamma(1-z)}$ satisfies $y''+ay=0$ and deduce it in that way. If so, with some other work I've done, it would give another way to show the product formula for $\sin$.

Comment: Just looking at the first two derivatives of $1/(\Gamma(z) \Gamma(1-z))$, I don't see a way to get this.  You might ask a new Question to see if anyone else has an insight.

Comment: @EricTowers I agree, it's unlikely to be possible. I just find it strange that the product formula for $\sin$ makes the truth that $\sin$ satisfies $y''+ y=0$ so opaque given that this is arguably its most fundamental property. I'll probably puzzle on it by myself for at least a few more days though.

Answer (score 1):

Set
$$
p(x)=\frac{1}{2}\big(y(x)+y(-x)\big) \qquad\text{Even part.}
$$
$$
m(x)=\frac{1}{2}\big(y(x)-y(-x)\big) \qquad\text{Odd part.}
$$
Then
$$
y(x)=p(x)+m(x), \\
y'(x)=p'(x)+m'(x), \\
y'(-x)=p'(-x)+m'(-x)=-p'(x)+m'(x)
$$
Hence
$$
y(x)+y'(-x)=\big(p(x)+m'(x)\big)+\big(m(x)-p'(x)\big)
$$
Where $p(x)+m'(x)$ even and $m(x)-p'(x)$ odd. So if $f=g+h$ (even, odd parts resp.) then we have the system
$$
p(x)+m'(x)=g(x), \\
m(x)-p'(x)=h(x), \\
$$
with $m(0)=0$, and $p(0)=p_0$. Or
$$
p'=m-h, \\
m'=-p+g.
$$

Solution.
$$
\binom{p}{m}'=
\left(\begin{array}{cc} 0 & 1 \\ -1& 0 \end{array}\right)
\binom{p}{m}
+\binom{-h}{g}, \qquad \binom{p(0)}{m(0)}=\binom{p_0}{0}
$$
and hence
$$
\binom{p(x)}{m(x)}=\left(\begin{array}{cc} \cos x & \sin x \\ -\sin x& \cos x \end{array}\right)\binom{p_0}{0}+\int_0^x 
\left(\begin{array}{cc} \cos (x-t) & \sin (x-t) \\ -\sin (x-t)& \cos (x-t) \end{array}\right)\binom{g(t)}{h(t)}\,dt.
$$
Thus
$$
p(x)=p_0\cos x+
\int_0^x\big(\cos(x-t)g(t)+\sin(x-t)h(t)\big)\,dt \\
m(x)=-p_0\sin x +
\int_0^x \big(-\sin(x-t)g(t)+\cos(x-t)h(t)\big)\,dt
$$
Finally,
$$
y(x)=p(x)+m(x)=\cdots=p_0(\cos x-\sin x)+\int_0^x\big(
f(x)\cos(x-t)-f(-x)\sin(x-t)\big)dt
$$